# iOS project compiled failed with error message "Reference to 'kGPBUnrecognizedEnumeratorValue' is ambiguous"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, protocol-buffers

I use Xcode to compile iOS project. Unfortunately, I've compiled failed, the error message is `Reference to 'kGPBUnrecognizedEnumeratorValue' is ambiguous`.

The 'kGPBUnrecognizedEnumeratorValue' is an enumeration type in the pod project `Protobuf (3.6.1)`.

It seems as, there are two 'kGPBUnrecognizedEnumeratorValue' defined in my OS environment.

So I think, it may be caused by the protobuf which I `brew install protobuf` yesterday. So I `brew uninstall protobuf` yet. But it makes no sense.

Who can solve this problem? Thanks.